# How to build a timer in Python for 0.1 steps

Tags: python, timer, rounding, clock

I use the following code to build a timer for a simulation in Python. Usually the timer runs in seconds but due to simulation studies I want the program to be faster and run in tenth of a seconds. (For this purpose the *10 is added in the code)

```
startTime = time.time()*10
while True:
    currentTimeOfSimulation = np.round(time.time()*10 - startTime, 1)
    print('current time', currentTimeOfSimulation)
```

I get the following output:

```
...
current time = 0.0
current time = 0.0
current time = 0.2
current time = 0.2
...
current time = 0.3
current time = 0.3
current time = 0.5
current time = 0.5
```

As you can see the step 0.1, 0.4, 0.7 are skipped. It seems that the same numbers are skipped every run. Why does this happen?

Edit: The timer should count from 0.0 to 1 in 0.1 steps with a duration of 0.1 seconds. Or in other words in one second the time should count from 0.0 to 10 in 0.1 steps. I did implement a timer that takes 1 second to count from 0.0 to 1 in 0.1. But due to simulation work I want the timer to count faster.
Thank you for you reply

Comment: There’s a delay and desyncranization between your `startTime` and `while` loop `time.time()` function. Because the startTime is not within your loop, it keeps using an old time value that is not the same. I recommend maybe placing the `startTime` within your loop.

Comment: You could print the un-rounded times, to have a better vision of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen due to precision lost from `np.round()`. But note that you don't need to use `numpy` for this, Python has a built-in `round()` function:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
while True:
    current_time_of_simulation = round((time.time() - start_time)/10, 1)
    print('current time', current_time_of_simulation)
```

Output:

```
current time 0.0
...
current time 0.1
...
current time 0.2
...
current time 0.3
...
current time 0.4
...
current time 0.5
...
current time 0.6
...
```

Comment: I did already try the round() function, but it didn't help. Additionally, your solution works fine. I was able to implement this succesfully aswell. But I need a timer that works in tenth of a seconds. Maybe I did not explain it well in my question above. I need a timer, that takes 1 second to count from 0.0 to 10 in 0.1 steps. Your solution takes a time of 1 second to count from 0.0 to 1.